# GitHub action to trigger batch codebuild for cypress e2e tests not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, cypress, github-actions, aws-codebuild

Anyone have any experience running the GitHub action [aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1](https://github.com/aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build)  and [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/)? Tests are not running in parallel. The IAM user has admin privileges so it can initiate batch builds.

When it works it runs tests sequentially. If I re-trigger the workflow manually in the logs I will see that it closes after starting the first test or there is a message from cypress dashboard saying the run will not continue as it had been canceled. For the ci-build-id I have been using $CODEBUILD_INITIATOR but on my most recent attempt to get this working I changed this to $COMMIT_INFO_SHA

[image]

[image]

Previously to this I have been using an action that triggers an AWS pipeline which uses the same exact codebuild and buildspec and it has been working fine. Problem with it is that the check will pass automatically as it just calls AWS to trigger the pipeline. Using aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1 monitors and reports the logs to Github so it will keep the check open until the test suite is completed and then fail or pass the check according to the test run results. Much easier to get devs to pay attention if it is right in their face ya know :p

Buildspec:
[image]

Github workflow:
[image]